# Modify article citation style using biber and verbose-trad1

Tags: biber

I'm using the style `verbose-trad1` in biber for my bibliography but I need to change the way it presents the Journal title and Number. They must be between parenthesis !

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}                   
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,
backend=biber,
bibencoding=inputenc,           
language=french,                
natbib=true,                    
sortcites=true,
autopunct=true,                     
hyperref=true,                          
block=space,
citetracker=true,
ibidpage=true,
ibidtracker=context,
idemtracker=true,
pagetracker=true,
url=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{articles.bib}

@article{Buis:2001aa,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Pierre Buis},
    Journal = {Cahiers Evangile},
    Keywords = {Bible, AT, Lévitique},
    Number = {116},
    Publisher = {Cerf},
    Title = {Le Lévitique : la Loi de sainteté},
    Year = {2001},
    }
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\fullcite{Buis:2001aa}

\end{document}
```

[image: Actual result]

Nevertheless, I'd like to have the following :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to do a `\renewbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,
backend=biber,
bibencoding=inputenc,
language=french,
natbib=true,
sortcites=true,
autopunct=true,
hyperref=true,
block=space,
citetracker=true,
ibidpage=true,
ibidtracker=context,
idemtracker=true,
pagetracker=true,
url=false,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{articles.bib}

@article{Buis:2001aa,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Pierre Buis},
    Journal = {Cahiers Evangile},
    Keywords = {Bible, AT, Lévitique},
    Number = {116},
    Publisher = {Cerf},
    Title = {Le Lévitique : la Loi de sainteté},
    Year = {2001},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{articles.bib}


\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \bibopenparen%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \bibcloseparen%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}


\begin{document}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\fullcite{Buis:2001aa}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]